# Java maven serenity project start chrome driver in mobile emulation mode

Tags: java, selenium

I have a maven project. I would like my chrome driver to start in mobile emulation mode. I saw some examples online, but all of them required to configure the driver in code. I would like to get this behaviour by using the `serenity.properties` file.

I tried to update/modify the driver, but I didn't manage to do so. If it's mandatory to be done by code, how could I intervene in the dependency injection/bean generation that is done with the help of the `serenity.properties` file?

By the examples that I saw online, I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
chrome_preferences.mobileEmulation.deviceName=iPhone X
```

My `serenity.properties` file:

```
chrome_preferences.mobileEmulation.deviceName=Apple iPhone X

webdriver.driver=chrome
webdriver.chrome.driver=C:/drivers/chromedriver.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out how to do it. Keep the `serenity.properties` file as follows:

```
webdriver.chrome.driver=C:/drivers/chromedriver.exe
webdriver.driver = provided
webdriver.provided.type = mydriver
webdriver.provided.mydriver = org.example.ChromeMobileDriver
thucydides.driver.capabilities = mydriver
```

and create a class as follows:

```java
public class ChromeMobileDriver implements DriverSource {
    @Override
    public WebDriver newDriver() {
        Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
        mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "iPhone X");

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

        return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean takesScreenshots() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Resources:

- https://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation
- http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_custom_webdriver_implementations